# Use pandas dataframe as dictionary in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I want to use a pandas dataframe as a dictionary. (I'm just a beginner Python-programmer so therefore the probably basic question)

```
Dictionary-dataframe:
Name     Age
Tom      45
Sam      87
Vif      23
Sep      65
Pol      71
```

Want I want is the following:
If df['Name'] == Sam return df['Age'], so in this case if I call for Sam, I want to see 87 in the output.

The code underneath is wrong of course, but this is what I want to see in the output.

```
print(df['Name'] == Sam)

Output: 87
```

Some code for the df:

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Tom', 'Sam', 'Vif', 'Sep', 'Pol'], 'Age':[45,87,23,65,71]})
```

Comment: `df[df['Name'] == 'Sam']`

Comment: Sounds like you need to read a Pandas tutorial, this is one of the most basic operations.

Comment: Jep probably, but you're code is not doing what I want. ;)  Gorlomi is right! Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following function:

You simply input the name in the function and it pulls out the value for you. Make sure it's between quotes.

```
def extractValue(i):
    return df[df.Name == i].iloc[0].Age

extractValue('Tom')
```

output:

```
45
```

the `df[df.Name == str(i)]` is to filter based on the name, the `iloc[0]` selects the first row and the `.Age` selects the column.